# Spring Cloud Config - File extension is not known to any PropertySourceLoader in Openshift

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-cloud-config

Here is my application.yml

```
spring:
  application:
    name: app
    version: @project.version@
  config:
    import: optional:configserver:${CLOUD_CONFIG_SERVER_URL}
  cloud:
    config:
      uri: ${CLOUD_CONFIG_SERVER_URL}
      username: ${CLOUD_CONFIG_USERNAME}
      password: ${CLOUD_CONFIG_PASSWORD}
      label: ${CLOUD_CONFIG_LABEL:develop}
```

The dependency I'm using is

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-config</artifactId>
        </dependency>
```

Spring Boot v2.4.5, Maven multi-module project. The application properties are in 'boot' module.

Locally everything is working, but in Openshift I always get:

"File extension is not known to any PropertySourceLoader. If the location is meant to reference a directory, it must end in '/'"

Not really sure what could be missed out.

Answer (score 4):

I have encountered with the same issue and I have resolved by adding "/" after config: import statement.

```
config:
    import: optional:configserver:${CLOUD_CONFIG_SERVER_URL}/
```